# How to join four tables in MySQL [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have four tables and I want to join all of them. I have successfully joined 3 tables, but when I try to join the fourth one, it doesn't work. I have set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and add `or die(mysqli_error($con));` to the end of my query but it doesn't show any errors, just a white screen.

It stopped working when I tried to join the votes table.

My tables are `votes` `users` `rings` `posts`

Here is my query:

```
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts p 
                                   INNER JOIN rings r ON p.rid = r.id 
                                   INNER JOIN users u ON p.uid = u.id 
                                   INNER JOIN votes v ON p.pid = v.pid 
                                   WHERE p.rid IN ('$rja') AND p.uid != '$uid' 
                                   AND p.deleted = '0' 
                                   ORDER BY p.date_posted DESC"
                           ) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

`$rja` is an array.

Votes Table:

```
vid | pid | uid | vote_type
```

Users Table:

```
id | username | password | email
```

Posts Table:

```
pid | uid | rid | body | votes | deleted | date_posted
```

Rings Table:

```
id | title | category | rating | user_created
```

If you have any questions please comment

Comment: You know, you can debug it, print the query on the screen and copy it to phpmyadmin or any other MySQL managing tool.

Comment: I copied it to phpMyAdmin already. It just said it was a success.

Comment: Besides saying it was a success, did it return any results? This query will only show posts that have votes.

Comment: It did not return any results

Comment: I inserted a couple votes into the database, it still does not show anything

Comment: when using inner join, at least one row with given criteria must exist in all tables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try left join

```
 SELECT * FROM posts p 
   INNER JOIN rings r ON p.rid = r.id 
   INNER JOIN users u ON p.uid = u.id 
   LEFT JOIN votes v ON p.pid = v.pid 
   WHERE p.rid IN ('$rja') AND p.uid != '$uid' 
   AND p.deleted = '0' 
   ORDER BY p.date_posted DESC"
```

Comment: Why a right join? I think it's more likely he needs a left join, so he can get posts with no votes.

Comment: A right join will find votes with no matching posts, which seems backwards.